# PHP + MySQL - ORDER BY LIKES

Tags: php, mysql

So I am using mysql to store likes on Minecraft Server Pages as a way for them to advertise. However, I am storing these likes in a separate table:

```
id user_id server_id
 1       1         1
 2       1        24
 4       2        22
 5       2        22
 6       2         1 
 7       2         4
 8       2         5
 9       2         6
10       2        17
11       2        18
12       2        21
13       2        24
```

Insert code:

```
INSERT INTO likes (user_id, server_id) VALUES ('".$user_id."', '".$server_id."');
```

But I am currently sorting them by date added (recent first) but I would like to know how to sort them by likes.

Comment: You have an insert statement. I assume your sorting is involved in a select statement? Let's see the select statement?

Comment: I've locked this question to stop you from continuing to roll back edits that substantially improve the post. This website is [collaboratively edited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). If you are not okay with that, this is probably not the site for you. The *reason* this was edited is because we don't allow pictures of textual content. Images aren't searchable, and aren't readable by users who use screen-readers. They're also harder to copy information out of for testing purposes, and thus discourage good answers. So, the person who replaced your image with text did you a big favor.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should put a counter column on your servers table (lets say: `likes_counter`) and then, every time you add a like to the likes table, you increment this counter. Put a index on that column tooo!

```
INSERT INTO likes (user_id, server_id) VALUES ('".$user_id."', '".$server_id."');
UPDATE servers_table SET likes_counter = likes_counter+1 WHERE server_id = '".$server_id."';
```

Now, when you select the servers, you only need to do a ordered by likes select:

```
SELECT * FROM servers_table ORDER BY likes_counter DESC;
```

Here i'm assuming your table of servers is named `servers_table`, replace it with the name you gave to the table.

Comment: Add an index? How would I do that?

Comment: I forgot to say that this is tottaly optional, but highly recommended! The index will increase the performance of the order being done. You should read about indexes at the docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: it isnt updating the likes_counter

Comment: Have you add the `likes_counter` column to your servers table?